# Fatal error: No default database configured

Tags: postgresql, heroku, vapor, vapor-fluent

When I try to do a migration of my database in heroku using vapor I get the following error when I run **heroku run Run -- migrate --env production**

FluentKit/Databases.swift:160: Fatal error: No default database configured.

I execute **heroku config** and created a database before migration.

Local migration works for me without problem. From a database management software if I can access the database without problem.

Thanks

Comment: How are you configuring the DB in configure.swift